# Trying to upload images to imgbb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, file-upload

I have been trying to upload images to imgbb from react using their api and my api key but it is not working i keep getting 400 error status code. below is the function

```
        if (e.target.name === 'img') {
         setImg(files[0]);
         setImagePreview(fileURLs[0]);
        } else {
          setImgArray(files);
          setImagePreview(fileURLs);
         }
        }

         async function uploadImage(){
         const data = new FormData();
         data.append('key', 'API_KEY');
         data.append('file', img);

        try{
          setUploadingImg(true);
          let res = await fetch('https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload', {
            method: 'post',
            body: data
          })
          const urlData = await res.json();
          setUploadingImg(false);
          return urlData.url
         }catch(err){
          setUploadingImg(false)
         console.log(err)
        }
       }
```

my form has two file inputs for image the first accept only one image file, while the second accept multiple images it will upload all images by sending multiple requests

```
type here
```

. but the upload function to upload to imgbb is not working. please what is wrong

i keep getting error status code of 400

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.